# Zipping many files and upload them to FTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, performance, optimization

I have a requirement of uploading several image files to FTP.

The main goal to achieve here is **performance, speed.**

My approach here is to, zip all files at client end, and ftp upload them and un-archive them back on server.

Is there any better approach??

and what is the best way to zip like 1000 images? Should I use .net inbuild mechanism OR some external library?

Note : I have VS 2012 development environment for this.

Comment: Images are usually already compressed, so zipping them will do nothing but waste time. Why not just upload them?

Comment: Uploading each file to FTP will cause this each file creation over head at FTp..

Comment: @James, what have you tried. I think in case of images just adding them to archive with `store` option would be enough. [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) offers multithreaded  approach to zipping files as I know

Comment: I have tried DotNetZip and .net inbuild mechanism to zip..but I am not sure which will give me performance benefits..

Comment: Also .. how much difference will it make to upload one archive in stead of single single file upload..

Answer (score 1):

`Zip it on the client` end and FTP it and `unzip them on the server` would be best approach in term of performance and speed. sending 1000+ files to the server will not be a ideal solution.

Better to use open source libraries to zip the files. You may use [Ionic Zip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). You can easily zip and unzip files using the exposed API.

**Code Sample**

Zipping Files

```
 using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
 {
     // add this map file into the "images" directory in the zip archive
     zip.AddFile("c:\\images\\personal\\7440-N49th.png", "images");

     zip.Save("MyZipFile.zip");
 }
```

Unzipping files

```
    public void ExtractZipFile(string fullZipFileName, string extractPath)
    {

        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(fullZipFileName))
        {
            //Extract the zip file
            zip.ExtractAll(extractPath);
        };
    }
```